# Syntax Error 4200 on a prepared statment with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi i try to execute the following prepared statment

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO cc_a (entite_juridique, enseigne_commerciale, raison_sociale, adresse, adresse2, cp, ville, country, region, departement, tel , email,  website , categorie, facebook,  twitter, google, siren, lieu_immat, capital, description, status) 
                          VALUES (:entite_juridique, :enseigne_commerciale, :raison_sociale,:adresse, :adresse2,:cp,:ville, :country, :region,  :departement, :tel, :email, :website, :categorie, :facebook,:twitter, :google, :siren,:lieu_immat, :capital, :description, :status)";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$sth->execute(array(':entite_juridique' => $entite_juridique, ':enseigne_commerciale' => $enseigne_commerciale,':raison_sociale' => $raison_sociale,
                    ':adresse' => $adresse, ':adresse2' => $adresse2,':cp' => $cp,
                    ':ville' => $ville, ':country' => $country, ':region' => $region,
                    ':departement' => $departement, ':tel' => $tel , ':email' => $email,
                    ':website' => $website , ':categorie'=> $categorie, ':facebook' => $facebook,
                    ':twitter' => $twitter, ':google' => $google, ':siren' => $siren,
                    ':lieu_immat' => $lieu_immat, ':capital' => $capital , ':description' => $description, ':status' => $status ));
```

but i got the followin error code.
I do not see where there is an error...

> Erreur : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   ':entite_juridique, :enseigne_commerciale, :raison_sociale,:adresse,
>   :adresse2,:c' at line 2

Is someone see why?

Comment: Echo your query out, you'll find the error.

Comment: how do you echo a prepared statment..., i mean you don't get the final statment...

Comment: You cannot, you'll have to do a string with variable injection.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be mixing `mysql` or `mysqli_` with PDO, are you? I can't see this failing otherwise, if you were using PDO exclusively.

Comment: you mean to replace all parameter with real values?

Comment: I was thinking the same as @Fred-ii-, that $dbh is an instance of `mysqli`, not `PDO`. Mysqli does not support named parameters.

Comment: Meaning, is your DB connection `mysqli`? As in `$dbh =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");`

Comment: Well good luck with that. I'm moving on.

Comment: I use only PDO not mysqli. Was is very strange is when I check on my db the values are well inserted....